# Is there a GUI client for PouchDB?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB in conjunction with node.js to store my documents on the server, but during the course of development a number of documents which are flawed or need to be deleted have begun accumulating in the DB.

Is there a GUI client like SQL Studio which allows me to connect to the DB and manually edit or delete the files ?

Comment: Install couchdb, then sync your pouchdb db's to that couchdb server. Done, you have the data in Fauxton

Answer (score 5):

You can access a version of Fauxton (the CouchDB GUI) via the [PouchDB Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pouchdb-inspector/hbhhpaojmpfimakffndmpmpndcmonkfa?hl=en) Chrome extension.

You can also access it by installing [pouchdb-server](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-server) and opening `http://localhost:5984/_utils` in a browser.

Comment: Thanks but the db I'm trying to look at is not in the browser but in node, I've looked at pouchdb-server but I can't get it to connect to the db I want, it only connects to some default db it starts with.

Comment: I don't know about connecting to pouchdb-server, but you could always replicated to pouchdb-server, then inspect it on the copy. I do know that there are no other decent GUIs available for pouch-db as I was looking for one for my project

Comment: The Chrome extension is no longer available. The `pouchdb-server` works fine for this